# Crossposting between Delicious and Tumblr so tags are synchronised

Tags: tumblr, delicious, tumblr-tags, delicious-tags

I rely heavily on del.icio.us (delicious.com) and would like to post select Delicious links to Tumblr. This can easily be done by feeding the RSS feed for my "to:tumblr" Delicious tag into Tumblr. However, I want the post that I send to Delicious and Tumblr to be tagged in the same way on both sites.

The delicious API supports outputting tag data, but I don't believe the Tumblr interface as-is pulls that data.

What's the easiest way to crosspost between Delicious and Tumblr?

Perhaps a fancy bookmarklet that lets me decide if I want to post to one or the other and posts tags to both?

I tried Ping.fm (now dead) a while ago, but I don't believe it was pushing the same tags to both services.

Comment: I've tried this using Posterous' [post.ly](http://post.ly) service, however it doesn't seem to post the actual link to delicious, just a link back to the posterous item (which then links to the actual link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [If This Then That](http://ifttt.com/) will do exactly this.  It will scan my Delicious or Pinboard feed and sync links to Tumblr as link posts *with* tags. Brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried your specific scenario, but [dlvr.it](http://dlvr.it/) allows you to distribute an RSS feed to Facebook, Twitter, Tumblr, etc. Try it and see if the tags go through. (Also, are you sure the tags are in delicious's feed? If not then it's not going to work no matter what.)

Comment: finally gave dlvr.it a try and it doesn't seem to post tags (or what they call 'categories' to tumblr), plus it adds its own link shortener to the posted link.

No sale, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: This sorta confirms the delicious API supports tags: http://getsatisfaction.com/tumblr/topics/pull_delicious_tags_for_imported_links#reply_1888955